# Change values of column in df using conditional in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having the following problem: I'm working with a dataset that can be found at https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ricardomattos05/jogos-do-campeonato-brasileiro

The column 'home_team' has 2 equal teams ('Atlético') and the difference between them is the column 'home_team_state'. How can I change the name of the teams in the data frame?

I tried to use some conditional like

```
df['home_team'] = np.where([df.home_team] == 'Atletico' and df['home_team_state'] == 'MG', 'Atlético MG', df.home_team)
```

but it does not work. So, basically, my question is: Can I change the specif values of a column in a Data Frame using the conditions of 2 columns?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `np.where(df["home_team"].eq('Atletico') & df['home_team_state'].eq('MG'), 'Atlético MG', df["home_team"])`

Comment: It does not work.  I have a function to get all the teams that played and when i use the df still gives me 2 "atleticos".

Answer (score 0):

You can't change but you can create a new one an then replace, like this.

In your case you can create 'home_team_copy':

```
df.loc[([df.home_team] == 'Atletico') | (df['home_team_state'] == 'MG'),  
'new_home_team]' = "<whatever you want, True or False,  YES OR NO, HOME 
TEAM..>"
```

Than, if was the case you replace the values or change de name os the column `new_home_team` to `home_team` for example.

Example:

| data | cts | op |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-24 | 3 | B |
| 2022-04-18 | 6 | S |
| 2017-04-14 | 10 | S |
| 2022-04-13 | 4 | S |

Code:

```
df.loc[(df['cts'] > 5) | (df['op'] == 'S'),  'obs'] = 
'flip'
```

And the output is:

| data | cts | op | obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-24 | 3 | B | NaN |
| 2022-04-18 | 6 | S | flip |
| 2017-04-14 | 10 | S | flip |
| 2022-04-13 | 4 | S | NaN |

Hope it helps :)